# Cast enum into key-value pair object in typescript

Tags: typescript, object, enums, casting

The use case is simple, I have an enum that I want to cast into a simple key-value pair object in typescript.

More than a question, this is how I solve it after diving into the docs, I hope this helps as reference for someone else.

Let's say you have the following enum definition:

```js
enum myEnum {
  A = "A",
  B = "B",
  C = "C+C",
  D = "Value of D",
}
```

and you want to cast the enum into the following:

```js
interface Obj {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was as follows:

```js
let obj: Obj = {};

for (var key in myEnum) {
  obj[key] = myEnum[key as keyof typeof myEnum];
}
```

As a result, you will end up with your enum casted to a key-value pair object as follows:

```
// key-value pair object from enum
{
  A: "A",
  B: "B",
  C: "C+C",
  D: "Value of D"
}
```

This works on `"typescript": "~3.7.5"`